# Can the css blur filter's value be dynamically updated?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, framer-motion

I am  trying to increase the amount of blur of a fixed pos text element as my page scrolls down. In other words, the pages scroll position should control the amount of blur.

I am using Framer sites (yes yes I know it's probably vanilla and all that, but I've got to start somewhere) for this, and wrote this override:

```
export function withBlur(Component): ComponentType {
    return (props: any) => {
        const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll()
        const modestScale = useTransform(
            scrollYProgress,
            (value) => 0.5 + value / 2
        )

        const blurAmount = 10
        const progressiveBlur = useTransform(
            scrollYProgress,
            (value) => value * 10
        )

        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                style={{
                    ...props.style,
                    WebkitFilter: `blur(${progressiveBlur}px)`,
                    filter: `blur(${progressiveBlur}px)`
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Link to non-working demo: https://super-architecture-699334.framer.app/

- passing a variable with a fixed value  (e.g. const blurAmount=10px) instead of progressiveBlur blurred the text
- Using scrollYProgress to change scale worked as expected

Am I flogging a dead horse, or is it possible to change he blur amount dynamically?

Comment: The current demo can't be modified to test out potential solutions and won't be useful to future users with a similar problem once you fix the issue on that domain. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar if you can't do it using a stack snippet.